# How can currency (USD/TRY) be going up without having a candle before that would close under it?

Tags: time-series, fx

I am having a hard time understanding how can USD/TRY be going up without having a period before that would close at a point under it. This is from today (2018-10-08 6:12 and 6:50). 
Is it moving up or down or is is a glitch?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out on my own, it was a huge spread gap.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a computer/ algo or a person that buys irrespective of price until a set point. Wild swings happen like this in thin markets.